# What function would be $\rm abs(\sin(x))$ over a circle (like flower petals)

Tags: functions, complex-numbers, circles

Imagine I have the equation of a unit circle.
I wish to draw (programmatically) something similar to $\rm abs(\sin(x))$ running over and around the circumference.

Just like drawing the external "petals" of a flower.

How can I proceed to create this equation of a half sine wave going around the circle (it would be nice if it were a simple equation I could write in code)?

Would it be easier by using the complex plane? Which is probably more difficult to program?

Comment: +1 for this nice question

Comment: Are you familiar with polar coordinates? If yes, are you looking for $ r = 1 + n |\sin x|$?

Comment: @Calvin Lin Thank you, I am looking at it using Desmos. Unless I am getting it wrong, I see only 2 big petals using x in (0,2pi). Ah I see, perhaps you mean n should multiply the angle x.

Comment: Yup, using $1+ n|sin mx|$ will give you $2m$ petals.

Comment: @ Calvin Lin. Thank you, that seems beautiful :-)